# Execute PHP from GIT post-update hook

Tags: php, git, hook, gitosis, githooks

I am using GIT on my server and I am trying to get a PHP file to be executed each time I update my repository. I'm trying to use my post-update hook to achieve this.

this is the code I tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo "**** Pulling changes into Prime [Hub's post-update hook]"
echo

cd $HOME/www || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull hub master

exec git-update-server-info

php /path/to/directory/file.php
```

I can't seem to get the PHP to execute. Anyone able to shine any light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exec` never returns. Anything you put after the `exec` call is dead code.

Remove the `exec`, or place it before your `php` line if that's the last thing that needs to be done. (And after doing error checking if necessary obviously.)

So for instance

```
...
git-update-server-info
exec php /path/to/directory/file.php
```

Or just simply

```
...
git-update-server-info
php /path/to/directory/file.php
```

(or move the statements around if your php script can be called before the git command.)

Comment: Awesome, I put the php command between "git pull" and "exec" and it worked like a charm. Thank you :-)